# Not able to connect from remote machine

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am not able to connect to my desktop from remote machines. I suspect some firewall mis-configuration. 
OS Details (Linux Mint 17):

```
11:16:23 ~ $ cat /etc/linuxmint/info 
RELEASE=17
CODENAME=qiana
EDITION="Cinnamon 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
DESKTOP=Gnome
TOOLKIT=GTK
NEW_FEATURES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_qiana_cinnamon_whatsnew.php
RELEASE_NOTES_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_qiana_cinnamon.php
USER_GUIDE_URL=http://www.linuxmint.com/documentation.php
GRUB_TITLE=Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit
```

Given below is the iptables output

```
11:05:29 ~ $ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 243 packets, 24661 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 60 packets, 3958 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I tried iptables -F as well.
When I restart iptables output goes to as below.

```
10:26:53 ~ $ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports mdns
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 4000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I tried gufw as well to disable firewall.
Any idea what could be wrong?
Am I looking at wrong place? Anything other than firewall could be the culprit?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from within your LAN or from outside?

Comment: Are you able to ping your machine from wherever you are trying to connect from?